# I can't append node groups

Tags: node-editor, groups, append

For some reason the node groups i try to append do not show up. what am i doing wrong? I linked a short clip of the group im trying to append and my problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRgEJPOx2Ec&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have appended the node group to the `.blend` file, however you are in the **compositing** editor, whereas your group is a **material** node group.

To switch to the `Material Editor` simply select an object in the scene, click this icon at the bottom of the window (see below), try adding it again and you should see your node group in the expected place (you might need to select the `Use nodes` checkbox again).

[image: Material Editor]